# Combine two different arrays with diffrent data

Tags: java, arrays

I have two diffrent arrays one students name and one with there last names

```
String[] firstname = {"Joe", "bryan", "moe", "zoe"};
String[] Lastname = {"May", "Zoey", "Eden", "Pratt"};
```

I was wondering how i would go on getting an output like where it prints the students first name then right next it the students last name

e.g   `Joe May ,Bryan Zoey`

I dont want to use print function to manually print each first and last name manually. I was wondering how i could print them all at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to an elegant answer by @YCF_L some more ways are given below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] firstNames = { "Joe", "bryan", "moe", "zoe" };
        String[] lastNames = { "May", "Zoey", "Eden", "Pratt" };

        // First method
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < firstNames.length && i < lastNames.length; i++) {
            sb.append(firstNames[i]).append(" ").append(lastNames[i]).append(", ");
        }
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 2); // delete the last comma
        System.out.println(sb);

        // Second method
        String fullNames[] = new String[firstNames.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < firstNames.length && i < lastNames.length; i++) {
            fullNames[i] = firstNames[i] + " " + lastNames[i];
        }
        String fullNamesStr = String.join(", ", fullNames);
        System.out.println(fullNamesStr);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Joe May, bryan Zoey, moe Eden, zoe Pratt 
Joe May, bryan Zoey, moe Eden, zoe Pratt
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Java stream you can use :

```
String[] fullName = IntStream.range(0, firstname.length)
        .mapToObj(i -> String.format("%s %s", firstname[i], lastname[i]))
        .toArray(String[]::new);
```

I based in the fact the two arrays have the same size.

Outputs

```
[Joe May, bryan Zoey, moe Eden, zoe Pratt]
```

Answer (score 0):

in java 8 ,considering the condition that arrays has same size.

```
ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<>();
  for(int i=0;i<firstname.length;i++)
   {
     al.add(fisrtname[i]+" "+lastname[i]);
   }
//now u have a complete arraylist with you with all the full names in it
```